# Convert R function to string

Tags: r, string, function

I would like to convert a function object into a string

```
fn=function(x)
{
  return(2*x)
}

my_convert_function(fn)

# would give 
#"fn=function(x)
#{
#  return(2*x)
#}"
```

Is it possible to do it ? Thank you for your ideas

Comment: How about `capture.output(fn)`

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
deparse(fn)
[1] "function (x) "     "{"                 "    return(2 * x)" "}"
```

Comment: Great option with deparse

Comment: @akrun any advantages to `paste(deparse(fn), collapse = "")` vs. `capture.output(fn)`?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns  I am not sure of any advantages.  But, the capture.output function seems to have a lot of if/else checks

Answer (score 0):

As of R 4.0, there is also `deparse1()`.  This version of `deparse()` returns a single string directly (if that is what you are looking for):

```
fn=function(x)
{
  return(2*x)
}
  
deparse1(fn)

#> [1] "function (x)  {     return(2 * x) }"
```